# Unable to display home page using curl after login

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get my home page after login using `CURL` but I don't
know why it is not displayed. I think something is wrong in my code;
Can you please check my code and let me know what's can be wrong with it?

```
<?php 
$file_contents=file_get_contents("https://www.bcarocks.com/");
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($file_contents);

$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
$imgs = $xpath->query('//*[@id="cimage"]');
foreach($imgs as $img)
{
    $imagesrc=$img->getAttribute('src') . PHP_EOL;
}
?>

<?php
//initial request with login data
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
      $user='test';
      $pass='test';
      $captcha=$_REQUEST['j_captcha'];
      $submit=$_REQUEST['submit'];
      $ch = curl_init();

      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.bcarocks.com/');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "j_username=$user&j_password=$pass&j_captcha=$captcha&submit=$submit");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie-name');  //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/var/www/ip4.x/file/tmp');  //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts
      $answer = curl_exec($ch);
      if (curl_error($ch)) {
          echo curl_error($ch);
      }

      //another request preserving the session

      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/home');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
      echo $answer = curl_exec($ch);
      if (curl_error($ch)) {
          echo curl_error($ch);
      }
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <img src="https://www.bcarocks.com/<?php echo $imagesrc;?>" />
    captcha:<input type="text" name="j_captcha" />
    <input id="loginbutton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"  />   
</form>
```

Comment: In the form you are refering to an `validateloginDetails()`, where is that?

Comment: it is just a validation for not entering blank textbox for captcha forgot about that now have a look again my code

Answer (score 0):

the page is loaded through curl, a possibility is that your login details are not correct. And you should always use urlencode() for every param you are sending.

Comment: my login details are correct that i know and i am able to login successfully through website ok now i have edited my correct username and password please have look you will be able to login using that in website

Answer (score 0):

it is because of you have fetched captcha here first and you are submitting it at time again you are accessing https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/loginHome.jsf page so it generates again new captcha for you but you have filled old captcha so does not match new captcha with old one 
got it???